# Kernel panic on wake from sleep with firewire peripheral plugged in

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, kernel-panic, firewire

I'm running OSX 10.9.2 on an old Macbook 5.2, 2.13Ghz C2d with 4 gigs of RAM.
Everything is very smooth except for one very big annoyance -

My mbox 2 pro has problems keeping up when waking up from sleep!

When waking up, I have a few seconds before the computer exits with the famous white screen telling me that a serious error has occurred.

When rebooting I get the following error log:

```
"

Anonymous UUID: 2813154B-E4FA-2C14-3696-90D94D9A51BB

Wed Mar 5 08:56:12 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8015edbe2e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f978c3af7, type 13=general protection, registers:

CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000105ca7053, CR3: 0x0000000018c05000, 

CR4: 0x000000000000066

etc .....

0xffffff808ebfbfb0 : 0xffffff8015ed6ff7 

Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
com.digidesign.fwfamily.driver(9.0f4)[EA9004EA-D8CD-1CA7-6281-17C82B2AF0EF]@0xffffff7f978b5000->0xffffff7f978d6fff

dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireAVC(4.2.2)[90DCC875-0911-3857-8D4E-838CA0149D3F]@0xffffff7f97310000

dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily(1.9.5fc2)[F387BB55-BB36-3C51-8BF5-3A957E30D539]@0xffffff7f9787e000

dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily(4.5.5)[C83215A8-3406-35EC-8C24-A1746E9565DF]@0xffffff7f96d83000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

"
```

I've made a fresh install on a new SSD drive with the latest drivers.

On Digidesigns' website it says that the drivers only support OSX 10.9.1.

That also showed this problem, but not even being able to boot with the sound card plugged in!

I'm considering downgrading to Snow Leopard or maybe Lion, the only reason I upgraded was that I'd like to use Logic Pro X as it fits my workflow better than LP9.

If anyone has any suggestions to how I should solve this, please advice.

Regards

/M

Comment: What and whos SSD is it? why r u getting drivers from ? web site? is that the OEM ? yes your error is with the digidesign.fwfamily.driver(9.0f4)

Comment: The drivers are for the Digidesign mbox2 pro. Can't believe i didn't manage to say What peripheral I am using..

Comment: I apologize, you did mention it, but I missed that in your question. Did you research with Digidesign for a solution.

Comment: My research shows that problem existed before 10.9 so just for fun Delete the sleepimage and let system recreate it by running this in terminal - sudo rm /Private/var/vm/sleepimage

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do any difference.

Comment: did you reset the SMC?, while monitoring your system configuration plug and unplug the firewire few times to see what is happening.